# Opens Source Parser for Generating Data Bindings from C?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, data-binding, gcc

Is there an Data Binding *Parser/Generator* of C header files (and/or Java jars) to generate [maybe] XML Data Binding for use/importing (or generating wrappers) into "other" languages? (eg [python](http://www.python.org/), [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29), [Go!](http://golang.org/) **and** [others](http://sourceforge.net/projects/algol68/))  This parser would used for cut down:

1. sharing procedures in libraries
2. data shunting to/from disk
3. inter-process messages

In the simplest case: Is there *already* a maintained "XML Data Binding" for [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/)? (Maybe there is a *magic* option in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) that generates the XML Data Bindings?)

Background example:  On [Tandem Guardian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_Computers) there is a DDL Compiler ("Data Definition Language") , basically the DDL language contains many [record definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_%28computer_science%29) , that can "compiled" by the DDL compiler to generate [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29)/[struct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29), [TAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_Application_Language)/struct, [Pascal/Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_programming_language#Type_declarations), [Fortran/named-commons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_language_features#Modules) or [COBOL/Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL#Data_types) declarations that can **then** be "included" when the C (or TAL/Pascal/Fortran/COBOL) program is compiled.  The DDL language makes the creating and the inter-language sharing of libraries very easy.  The DDL output could **also** be used for both shunting data to/from disk and in [inter-process messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), hence easily sharing data between programs written in different languages.

Some close contemporary examples:

C++ permits the **direct** importing of C header files, eg:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "header.h"
}
```

Python specifically permits the parsing of GTK C libraries, and the generation of python wrapper modules with [PyGTK-Codegen](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/PyGTK-Codegen) via "Defs" files:

```
(define-object name
  (in-module "module")
  (docstring "doc")
  (parent "parent")
  (c-name "name")
  (gtype-id "id")
  (fields
    ("type" "name")
    ...
  )
  (implements "interface")
)
```

In a way [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)s half solve the problem of IPC between different CPU architectures. But not local data binding declarations problem to other languages.

In the first instance an open-source tool parsing for just C generating XML would be great (and one from java a real bonus). If it this parser is already on a major Linux distribution even better.

I have spotted Parser summary at:  [XML Data Binding Tools](http://www.xmldatabinding.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote:

> [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) is a software development tool
> that connects programs written in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_programming_language)
> and [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) with a variety of high-level
> programming languages. SWIG is used
> with different types of target
> languages including common scripting
> languages such as [Perl](http://www.perl.org/), [PHP](http://www.php.net/), [Python](http://www.python.org/),
> [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/) and [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/). The list of supported
> languages also includes non-scripting
> languages such as [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809), Common Lisp
> ([CLISP](http://www.cliki.net/clisp), [Allegro CL](http://www.franz.com/products/allegrocl/), [CFFI](http://www.common-lisp.org/project/cffi/), [UFFI](http://uffi.b9.com/)), [D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/),
> [Go language](http://golang.org/), [Java](http://www.java.com/en/), [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), [Modula-3](http://www.modula3.org/), [OCAML](http://caml.inria.fr/),
> [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), [Pike](http://pike.ida.liu.se/)(?) and [R](http://www.r-project.org/). Also several interpreted
> and compiled Scheme implementations
> ([Guile](http://www.gnu.org/s/guile/), [MzScheme/Racket](http://racket-lang.org/), [Chicken](http://www.call-cc.org/)) are
> supported.
>
> SWIG is most commonly used
> to create high-level interpreted or
> compiled programming environments,
> user interfaces, and as a tool for
> testing and prototyping C/C++
> software. SWIG is typically used to
> parse C/C++ interfaces and generate
> the 'glue code' required for the above
> target languages to call into the
> C/C++ code. SWIG can also export its
> parse tree in the form of [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) and Lisp
> [s-expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression).

Supports:

- FreeBSD/OpenBSD/NetBSD
- HP-UX
- Linux
- Mac OS X
- Solaris
- Windows 95/98/NT/2000/XP/Vista

Also: For [Serialisation of C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#C.2FC.2B.2B) the package ["Cerialization" (s11n/c11n)](http://s11n.net/c11n/) can be used. It includes
funtxt (text), [funxml](http://libfunutil.sourceforge.net) (basic XML dialect), simplexml (leaner XML dialect), compact (non-human), parens ([emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)-friendly), [wesnoth](http://expat.sourceforge.net), [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net), [sqlite](http://s11n.net/sqlite/sqlite3_serializer) & [mysql](http://s11n.net/mysql/mysql_serializer).

Comment: @Stephen_C 57.4k: I loved your original answer. I'm about to "Accept" my own answer?!? This feels kind of strange, esp as there is a bounty involved. Can you put up more detailed answer so my bounty isn't wasted. BTW: SWIG looks perfect, some other utilities worth considering: JNA, GlueGen, kross, F2PY, OSID, XPCOM etc

Answer (score 0):

my friend parse C files manually via python script and generate necessary output via cog.

ragel already have C-parser, but generate feature must be added personally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want but may be [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) can be used for this purpose and there is already [grammar written for C](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list), so you can directly use this one.